# How to create a conditional-OR if statement that runs multiple times if multiple conditions are true

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization, multiple-conditions

Right now my code has 52 checkboxes that each return their own value.

```
if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                x += 1;
            }
if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(1) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                x += 2;
            }
if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(2) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                x += 1;
            }
```

I want to group if statements that do the same thing into a single statement, something like

```
if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0) == CheckState.Checked ||
    checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(2) == CheckState.Checked ||
    checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(17) == CheckState.Checked )
            {
                x += 1;
            }
```

However such a code would only run once. Is there an operator that would help in this situation or would I have to just write 52 if statements.

Comment: What determines what you're incrementing `x` by? This is crying out for a loop, but until I know whether you're incremented `x` by `1` or `2` I can't figure out how it'd be written.

Comment: Your actual requirement is to get the number of checked check boxes in the checkbox list, isn't it?

Comment: The checked list is a point system and different things on the list give different amount of points.


EDIT: More specifically it's the yaku list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Mahjong_yaku each yaku gives a specific amount of han and I'm using a checked box to calculate how many han you have based on what you got.

Comment: You don't need any of the IF conditions. Just loop through *CheckedListBox.CheckedItems* and increment *x* variable.

Comment: @vnikhil - you're missing the point of his requirement.

Comment: Can you add GetItemCheckState() in a simple generalised way, so that we will have some idea for optimization.

Comment: Woah did not expect this question to explode when I went to sleep. There appears to be a few misunderstandings with some of you and I apologize. I probably could've made it more clear in the question.

I chose Matthew's answer because I thought it was the most elegant and useful for what I wanted to do. Also using the yaku class it solved my next issue with figuring out whether to reward X han or Y han depending if the hand is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an `int[]` array of scores with one entry for each possible checkbox:

```
var scores = new []
{
    1,
    2,
    1,
    4,
    2,
    1,
    // Etc up to 52 items
};
```

Then you can just loop though all the checkboxes and add up all the scores:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i)) == CheckState.Checked)
        x += scores[i];
```

You could also use `CheckedListBox.CheckedIndices` to iterate through the checked items, which would look like this:

```
x = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().Sum(i=> scores[i]);
```

A much better way to approach this, IMO, is to write a special `Yaku` class which is used to hold information about each item in the list. This would include the name and the score (han). It would also override `ToString()` so that the name would be displayed in the list.

It could look a bit like this:

```
public class Yaku
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int    Han  { get; }

    public Yaku(string name, int han)
    {
        Name = name;
        Han  = han;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then you could initialise the checked list box somewhere like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Yaku("Little three dragons",  4));
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Yaku("Terminal in each set",  3));
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Yaku("Three closed triplets", 3));
}
```

And add up the scores like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int score = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<Yaku>().Sum(item => item.Han);
    MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This gets my upvote. The only other answer that seems to acknowledge a variation in scores (a sigh of relief). Although I would argue that for maintainability's sake the yaku objects were kept in a list somewhere if they're to be used again. It's not clear to see from your `int[]` which score belongs to which `yaku`.

Comment: @JayMee Agreed, and I'd really prefer to store an object with each list item (using the `.Tag` property) which includes the score, then you'd just just use that to get the score to add. But I think that would be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Nice! I was unaware of `.Tag`.

Comment: @JayMee Sorry, I was getting confused with another type of control which has `Tag`. However, there's a good way to do this, and I'm about to post an example.

Comment: @downvoter: It's useful to indicate why you are downvoting. Otherwise it's hard to know what's wrong (if anything).

Answer (score -3):

Put the indices of checkboxes in a list / array:

```
using System.Linq;

...
var checkboxIndices = { 0, 2, 17 };
x += checkboxIndices.Count(index =>
         checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(index) == CheckState.Checked);
```

Edit: Sigh, I though it was obvious but here's the same thing with more details:

```
  class Yaku
   {
       public Yaku(List<int> indices, int han)
       {
           Indices = indices;
           HanValue = han;
       }
       public List<int> Indices;
       public int HanValue;
       public int ComputeValue(CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
       {
            return HanValue * Indices.Count(index =>
                checkedListBox.GetItemCheckState(index) == CheckState.Checked);
       }
   }

   ...
   var yakus = [
       new Yaku({0, 2, 17 }, 1),
       new Yaku({1}, 2)
       ...
   ];
   var totalYakuValue = yakus.Aggregate(yaku => yaku.ComputeValue());
```

Comment: You, too, are missing the point of his requirement. Read the comments on the OP.

Comment: Requirement is different than what you are suggesting. The counter to increment is different based on cases

Comment: What do you mean the counter is different? Increment another variable? Increment by more than 1? The code above can be trivially changed to match both of these.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff - each checklist has a different "han", which is a value by which you must increment `x`. You haven't mentioned how to retrieve this value.

Comment: The OP has not mentioned either so I assume it's hardcoded?

Comment: @Nikita Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes @Nikola, the value with which x is to be incremented is different.

Comment: Wasn't it obvious from the beginning that this is a trivial extension?